# Auditing DFS file deletion attempts on Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server, event-viewer

I'm configuring a DFS system consisting of 3 machines, a domain controller(Server 2016) and 2 member servers(Server 2016 and Server 2012 R2). The domain controller won't be hosting the DFS server, and instead my 2 member servers will be hosting it with file replication.

I need to audit any file deletion attempts, whether successful or not, in the DFS folder, which I called SharedFolder01. The logs produced will then have to be extracted and put into a text file.

The text file should only contain the date/time of attempt, file/folder name, attemptors username and whether the deletion succeeded or failed.

I created a GPO using Audit File System, which will audit Success and Failure. However, in the event viewer it only shows the successful delete attempts and not the failed ones.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Setting up file system auditing, especially for **deletion events**

1. Navigate to the file share, right-click it and select "**Properties**" →
   Select the "**Security**" tab → Click the "**Advanced**" button → Go to the
   "**Auditing**" tab → Click the "**Add**" button → Select the following:

> Principal: "Everyone"
> Type: "All"
> Applies to: "This folder,subfolders and files"
> Advanced Permissions: "Delete subfolders and files" and "Delete"

2. Run the Group Policy editor (**gpedit.msc**) and create and edit a new GPO. Specifically, go to → **Computer Configuration → Policies → Windows Settings** → **Security Settings → Local Policies → Audit Policy**, and setup as following:

> Audit object access → Define → Success and Failures.

3. Go to "**Advanced Audit Policy Configuration**" → **Audit Policies → Object Access**, and setup as following:

> Audit File System → Define → Success and Failures
> Audit Handle Manipulation → Define → Success and Failures

4. Link the new GPO to your file server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I have tried Audit Handle Manipulation. The main issue there is that the Audit Failure is repeated 4 times in event viewer for each failed delete. What could be the issue there?

Comment: I would imagine that is how it should behave. Each failed delete should have a an event associated with it in the event viewer. Apologies if I have misunderstood your question

Comment: I'm sorry I should have phrased it better. I meant that when I have 1 failed delete, 4 events occur at the exact same time for that 1 failed delete, all of them telling me the same thing.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Do you have any screenshots ? Please try to ensure to provide as much detailed information as possible

Comment: I have run into a problem. After trying to reimplement the failed delete capture, it is not captured in event viewer. On the other hand, successful file deletion is logged under Event ID 4659.

Comment: Unfortunately, your comments are not in detail apart from saying you have run into a problem. This doesn't help to answer this question anymore. If you feel the original answer provided has helped you with some guidance, please mark it as useful or upvote. Thanks